# Does await wait until the .catch has finished

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

does a promise wait until the catch is over or not? So in this example, is the "1 or 2" first shown or is "first or second" shown first?

```
await promise().catch(()=>{
    await anotherPromise();
    alert("1 or 2");
});
alert("first or second");
```

Comment: Try it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

```
Alert("1 or 2");
```

will be shown first.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So the await waits always, until the .catch method of itself has finished. The same with the .then( ) method?

Comment: Yes, you can have a quick read through this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

It explains it in detail

Comment: You are welcome, if this has answered your question please consider accepting the answer for future reference by other users.

Comment: @dragomir you havent provided a real answer, so thats not really a future reference :/

Answer (score 1):

As by [operator predescendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), nearly nothing can beat the function call and the property access operator. So independently of what you do there:

```
await a.b.c().d;
```

It will be first evalued, then the result is awaited. So it doesnt await the result of

```
promise()
```

but rather the result of

```
promise.catch(..)
```

which will return a new promise. So your code is equal to:

```
 promise().catch(()=>{
   await anotherPromise();
   alert("1 or 2");
 }).then(()=> alert("first or second") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `await` awaits the promise, and [`.catch(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) returns a promise that resolves with the result of the callback (which in your case is a promise).

However, you forgot to make the callback function `async`, using `await` in there would throw a syntax error. And you wouldn't write it like this anyway - rather use

```
try {
    await promise();
} catch {
    await anotherPromise();
    alert("first");
}
alert("second");
```

which also makes clear in which order the alerts can happen.

Comment: Im still amused about the first answer... This is probably more accurate